# Syntax Error - Unexpected identifier -(final line of code)

Tags: javascript, function

I'm getting an unexpected identifier error in chrome for the last line of this code, does anyone know why? thanks (updated to entire code for the page)
It's supposed to display a list of data for the jobs ive got entered into a database

```
    <?php
error_reporting(0);
include('../includes/header.php');
include('connection.php');
?>


<script src="../jqm/demos/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var db;
    $(document).ready(function () {
    loadJobRecords();    
    }

$(document).on("click", "#jobRecord", function () {
     getJobById($(this).data("key"));
    });
    });

function loadJobRecords() {
    db.transaction(function (txs) {
        txs.executeSql('SELECT * FROM jobs', [], function (txs, results) {
            var len = results.rows.length, i;
                 for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                     var JobRecord = results.rows.item(i);

                     var individualJob = '';
                     individualJob = '<li><a href="#detailinfo" id="jobRecord" data-key="' + jobRecord.ID + '" >';
                     individualJob += '<h3>' + jobRecord.Title + '</h3>';
                     individualJob += '<p>Testing</p>';
                     individualJob += '</a></li>';

                     $('#listofjobs ul').append(individualJob);
                     $('#listofjobs ul:visible').listview('refresh');
                 }
             });
         });
 }

    function getJobById(id) {

         db.transaction(function (txs) {
             txs.executeSql('SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE id="' + ID + '"', [], function (txs, results) '){
                var len = results.rows.length, i;

                 for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                     var jobRecord = results.rows.item(i);
                     var individualjob = '';
                     individualjob += '<h3>' + jobRecord.Title + '</h3>';
                     individualjob += '<p>' + jobRecord.Description + '</p>';
                     individualjob += '<p>' + jobRecord.Username + '</p>';

                     $('#jobSummary').html(individualJob); 
                 } 
             });
         });
     }    

</script>

    <div class="content container">
    <div daa-role="page" id="jobsdatabase">
        <section>
    <div data-role="content" id="listofjobs">               
        <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-inset="true">

         </ul>
        </section>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

<?php include('../includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: this is the code for the whole page

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the jquery selector doesn't find a match?

Try going to the console in chrome and running:

```
$('#listofjobs ul:visible').length
```

Is the value greater than 0?

Comment: Just to be clear, is the error occurring on the line of code $('#listofjobs ul:visible').listview('refresh'); I notice you updated your post and this was originally the last line of the original sample.

Comment: the function "loadjobrecords" is what is causing me problems I'm now getting "unexpected token function"

Answer (score 0):

Change to this

```
var db;
$(document).ready(function () {
    loadJobRecords();    


    $(document).on("click", "#jobRecord", function () {
        getJobById($(this).data("key"));
    });
});

function loadJobRecords() { ...
```

You have a quote ' and bracket at the end of this line, just after results - remove them

```
txs.executeSql('SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE id="' + ID + '"', [], function (txs, results) '){
```

change to

```
txs.executeSql('SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE id="' + ID + '"', [], function (txs, results){
```

Comment: this function is now causing the issue "unexpected token function"

Comment: Updated post see second part.